# Cargo build hangs with " Blocking waiting for file lock on the registry index" after building parity from source

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I followed the [readme](https://github.com/paritytech/parity#build-from-source) instructions for building [Parity](https://www.parity.io/) from source and then executed:

```
cargo build --release
~/.cargo/bin/cargo build --release
```

as instructed, both of which returned the following message while the prompt hung:

```
 Blocking waiting for file lock on the registry index
```

I'm on a Mac.

Comment: The problem for me was that my rust-analyzer vscode plugin was indexing. Once it finished, running `cargo run` worked fine.

Comment: I've the same problem on Linux when using Rustler to use Rust codes in Elixir. The problem resolved by removing `~/.cargo/.package-cache` as mentioned it this issue https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9742.

Comment: My problem was that I installed both Rust and rust-analyzer on VS Code at the same time. The problem was fixed after I removed either of the extensions. Hope this helps!

Comment: VSCode was my hang up as @oriont stated. I just needed to wait for the rust-analyzer to finish whatever it was doing.

Comment: I'm sure this will only apply to a small percentage of users, but for me, restarting Visual Studio Code fixed the problem

Comment: @oriont is right. I encountered this problem when my rust-analyser is indexing.

Comment: I had the same problem as @oriont. The rust-analyzer extension for VSCode was busy. As soon as it finished, my `cargo run` command proceeded.

Comment: why parity? me too!

Comment: I restarted VSCode and the error stopped.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

I suggest looking at '[Cargo build hangs with " Blocking waiting for file lock on the registry index" after building parity from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565203/cargo-build-hangs-with-blocking-waiting-for-file-lock-on-the-registry-index-a#answer-53066206)' first.

I had the same issue and had success with a quick and dirty

```
rm -rf ~/.cargo/registry/index/* ~/.cargo/.package-cache
```

Comment: Worked for me after 30s of waiting, without doing anything.

Comment: I had to remove `~/.cargo/.package-cache` as well.

Comment: For me, I suspect it's the `rust-analyzer` extension in VS Code. While it's downloading its components (after I open the project) I get the blocking problem.

Comment: worked for me after deleting both `.cargo/registry/index` and `.package-cache`

Comment: I removed `rm -rf ~/.cargo/registry/cache/*` for Error `Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache`  to make it work.

Comment: This answer should be updated to include what @tadman added.

Comment: It works, but I have to run those commands multiples times during the day... There is no long-term solution ?

Comment: that's scary, i choose `cargo clean `

Comment: I disabled `rust-analyzer` and it magically began working.

Answer (score 235):

Running `cargo clean` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Seems less hacky, but for some reason only the accepted answer solved my problem. Is it doing the same?

Comment: @FelixJassler No. It deletes the entire target folder of the project you run this command for, unlike the accepted answer.

Comment: must note this for next time! Had already done the manual remove of the `~/.cargo/.package-cache` per @ali-shirvani and it worked a treat

Comment: that's how I got it. I.e. Ran "cargo clean" and then build stuck on "Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache"

Comment: worked for me. I'm using it in a devcontainer which seems to screwed things up when building it the first time. Cargo clean did the job tho.

Comment: can explain the magic?

Answer (score 170):

This happens when you run two compilations of the same project at the same time. The compiler uses a lock file to avoid having data race issues.

There are some possibilities:

- If you ran the two compilations yourself, the solution is obvious: you need to cancel one of them.
- If you use an IDE that automatically compiles your project: you can wait for the job to be finished or close the IDE. If it does not work, this is probably because of RLS hanging out. You can run `pkill rls` to solve the issue.
- As a last resort, you can force the removal of the lock using `rm -rf ~/.cargo/registry/index/*` as said in [jvatic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47855850/4498831).

Comment: This is correct, in my case it was the cargo extension in VS Code which was automatically compiling my project

Comment: Same as @HomamBahrani. I think this answer reveal the root cause should be ranked higher.

Comment: My apologizes but where is this .cargo/registry/index/ located? I can't seem to find it in the project directory, the only folders there are src, target and .gitignore

Comment: @AbdullahAshraf It's not in your project, it's in your home, like `/home/user/.cargo/registry/index`

Comment: @Boiethios Thanks for helping out. I forgot to mention but I'm on windows. Also, it worked after waiting for about 3-5 minutes. Since then, there was no wait.

Answer (score 73):

It is important to ensure you have no other rls or cargo running. 
`sudo pkill rls cargo` is a good way to ensure they are not.

Comment: In my case it was just the cargo process that was still running. Killing that process fixed it for me.

Comment: For me, neither the most popular answer nor the accepted answer worked. But this worked.

Comment: This answer needs to be on the top

Comment: This saved me lots of hours, the other answers not worked for me but this.

Comment: The same issue also got my `Cargo.toml` metadata file locked when I run the second `cargo` process it was just stuck. After I found another `cargo` process never responded and terminated I just sent signal to killed it, problem solved without deleting any lock file or the entire folder at `.cargo` :).

Answer (score 41):

Removing `rm $CARGO_HOME/.package-cache` worked for me.

I accidentally hit `ctrl+z` instead of `ctrl+c` while executing `cargo run` and the next execution of `cargo run` showed me `Blocking waiting for file lock on the registry index`. I removed the said file and then it worked again.

*Edit:*
If you accidentally hit `ctrl+z` like me, you can unsuspend the `cargo run` process by running `fg` instead of deleting the package cache file. `ctrl+z` actually sends a SIGTSTP signal to the process and that process will be suspended until you tell it to continue. See this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/262948/826580) for more info.

Comment: I have closed my IDE while compiling. This solution was fixed my issue.

Comment: Yup, I had `^Z` inside Neovim and it must have been in the middle of some `cargo check`  (or similar) pass when I did so.

Comment: This worked in windows for me.

Answer (score 31):

I am using this command in macOS Monterey 12.4:

```
rm -rf ~/.cargo/.package-cache
```

then rerun the build command, works.

Comment: In my case, it's the correct solution.

Comment: This works for me too. I was on Mac 14.0

Answer (score 21):

You usually get this error when you run the `cargo build` command twice at the same time. If you are using an IDE check if a plugin is running a cargo command in the background, this was the case for me with VS Code.

Answer (score 18):

My issue was the IDE was running cargo and had locked the directory. Try closing your IDE

Answer (score 12):

My VSCode intellisense was working on a build. Make sure your intellisense is not builing. It displays a little gear icon spinning on bottom. Happens mostly when you update `Cargo.toml`

Answer (score 12):

You can point your IDE to use a different path when building the code.
This will prevent conflicts with locks in the future. Add the following compile flags to the IDE:

```
--target-dir target/rls/
```

In VSCode use the following setting:

```
"rust-analyzer.runnables.extraArgs": [
  "--target-dir",
  "target/rls/"
]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't help, because cargo still stores and reads the global package cache in the `~/.cargo` directory, not in the current project's target directory.

Comment: worked for me on ubuntu 22 with tauri app

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this issue by running the following commands:

1. Search for all `rust` related processes by `$ ps aux | grep rls`
2. Stop all of them one by one with `$ sudo kill -9 <PID>`

Comment: This is what happened to me. The rustc process was not responding and locking the directory. None of the other answers worked and came here to add a reply explaining the same.

Comment: The PID changes before you get a chance to kill it

Comment: @LukeSchoen the PID isn't changing, the process is restarting or being respawned with a new PID. Try `sudo pkill rls cargo` which finds and kills all instances.

Answer (score 6):

Same issue in VScode : if you've installed RLS

1. File | Preferences | Settings
2. Search for "rls"
3. In "rust" extension, uncheck "Start RLS automatically when opening a file or project"

Re-open your project, and it should be solved.

Answer (score 5):

it's work for me on the linux (ubuntu) :

```
$ rm ~/.cargo/.package-cache
```

Answer (score 5):

Windows: i opened the task manager and end the Cargos processes

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This helped to resolve the issue  `rm ~/.cargo/.package-cache`

Blocking started after I added rand = "0.8.5" to my cargo.toml.

Answer (score 4):

Before removing the Cargo registry index as suggested in the accepted answer, make sure no other process is currently compiling Parity or any other Rust package.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to create a Polkadot Node by following the [Readme](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot) instructions.

I was able to build it by running the following commands (copy/paste into Bash Terminal):

```
git clone https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot;
cd polkadot; git checkout master;
rustup update nightly;
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly;
rustup update stable;
rustup default stable;
cargo install --git https://github.com/alexcrichton/wasm-gc --force;
cargo install --git https://github.com/pepyakin/wasm-export-table.git --force;
brew install openssl; brew upgrade openssl;
rustc --version; cargo --version;
./build.sh;
cargo build;
cargo run -- --help;
./target/debug/polkadot --help;
```

I then tried to run a Polkadot Node with the following commands (which are equivalent):

```
./target/debug/polkadot -- --chain=dev --validator --key Alice -d /tmp/alice;
cargo run -- --chain=dev --validator --key Alice -d /tmp/alice;
```

But instead it showed the following:

```
Blocking waiting for file lock on the git checkouts
Blocking waiting for file lock on build directory
```

I found it was caused by CLion (Jetbrains IDE).

I solved the problem by closing CLion. I used Visual Studio Code editor instead, which also allows for debugging Rust code with breakpoints

Comment: The short answer is: If you have a Jetbrains IDE open, try closing it. Happened to me on Linux + IDEA.

Answer (score 3):

if you ever hit "Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache",

Run the command below and run cargo again.
rm $CARGO_HOME/.package-cache

Answer (score 3):

I had a case where there was an update to my rust extension `rust-analyzer` in vscode that was causing it. I updated and reloaded the extension and then `cargo build` ran fine.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was another process using cargo. I could not find the process to kill so I restarted my local machine and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS Sonoma 14.1.1, the way I fixed `Blocking waiting for file lock on the registry index` when I was trying to run `cargo build` was to open the Activity Monitor application:

- Press CMD + Space, then type "Activity Monitor.app"
- Click the CPU tab, and enter "cargo" in the search input field at the top right. [image]
- Select all processes with "cargo" in the "Process Name" column
- Click the (X) icon and choose "Force Quit" those processes
- Wait for about a minute or so for those `cargo` processes to quit
- Re-run your `cargo build` command without it hanging.

Note: I tried other solutions like quitting VSCode but that wasn't the cause in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

### What worked for me

For me, I found that the issue was caused by configuring my target dir:

```
[build]
target-dir = ".cargo/target"
```

in my `.cargo/config`.

### What didn't work

I ran `cargo build --release -vv` and saw a message that didn't appear without the `-vv` flag:

```
Blocking waiting for file lock on build directory
```

I thought this a big clue so I tried stuff like disabling my file backups. I also tried all the answers on this page with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Finally. And I absolutely mean finally when all fails and you want a quick out. Restart your machine.
Perhaps it's also the rust-analyzer taking way too long so don't open vscode on reboot, use your terminal instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use cargo clean and re-run the cargo run command and wait for some time. This usually happens when you try to use a new module in your code by adding it into Cargo.toml file.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when `cargo run` but nothing work for me i restart my system and problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Temporarily Stop the ***`rls`*** Process.

Comment: There is an existing answer that covers this. Can you expand on this answer?

Answer (score 0):

On the risk of coming late to the party, while cargo, rls or rust-analyzer are responsible for the lock to avoid data races.
An underlying issue maybe the number of `inotify filewatchers`.

Usually they work fine by spawning a new watcher and wait their turn but if they run out of watchers space this can be a problem.
Agreeing to all the above solutions but suggesting to check the number of `max_user_watches`

```
# view current settings
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

# increasing it, /etc/sysctl.conf
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288

# The new value can then be loaded in by running s
$sudo sysctl -p.
```

Answer (score 0):

For me rust analyzer didn't stop and closing the IDE didn't help. But instead of shutting the computer just close the IDE and go into task manager (this is at least for windows). In task manager under details tab you can find any cargo processes that may be running and kill them there. Then you can reopen IDE and you should be back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the cargo process that is running in the background, it should fix.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue

Actually, on another terminal, I was running my debugger and that's why this command was blocked.
So just stopped the debugger and then ran the command and everything went fine.

Answer (score -3):

If you are sure that there is no other cargo process executing, but this problem still occur frequently, it might be your network problem.