# How to solve ”Blocking waiting for file lock on build directory“ problem?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to generate some .rs code in my rust program, and I create a package `gen-proxy-ffi` which use `bindgen` to do that. The following command can generate codes I need.

```
cargo run --package gen-proxy-ffi --bin gen-proxy-ffi
```

When the codes are generated, I can then build the whole project by

```
cargo build
```

Now, I want `cargo build` will automaticly generate code by calling `cargo run --package gen-proxy-ffi --bin gen-proxy-ffi`. I know I can write some code to build.rs to specify rust's compiling routine, so I write the following codes, where make-gen-proxy-ffi.sh encaplsules `cargo run --package gen-proxy-ffi --bin gen-proxy-ffi`.

```
// build.rs
use std::process::Command;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let o = Command::new("sh").args(&["make-gen-proxy-ffi.sh"]).output().expect("sh exec error!");
}
```

However, when running `cargo build` now, it prints out the following error

```
+ cargo run --package gen-proxy-ffi --bin gen-proxy-ffi --
    Blocking waiting for file lock on build directory
```

After some [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565203/cargo-build-hangs-with-blocking-waiting-for-file-lock-on-the-registry-index-a), I know it is because  `cargo build` on the same project twice at one time.

However, from this post, I found no solution to this, so I wonder if there are any ways I can generate code and build the whole project by one `cargo build`?

Comment: I would've hoped setting a different `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` would help, but I'm not getting any success with that