# Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache when I added dependency to Cargo.toml file

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo

I added a dependency to a rust project, then ran cargo run, this gave me this error:

"Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache"

I tried the solution I found online which was to delete the ~/.cargo/.package-cache file, however this has not worked for me. When I type commands like cargo run and cargo update I just get the same message.
Now even when I go to another rust project with no dependencies, and try to run it, I get the same "Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache" message.
I am on a M1 MacBook Pro.

Comment: Do you have rust-analyzer running in the background?

Comment: Hi, I think so, however it is now showing an error: rust-analyser failed to load workspace: Failed to read Cargo metadata from Cargo.toml file

Comment: If you stop rust-analyzer, does it work?

Comment: will it stop if I disable it on the extensions tab?

Comment: IDK, maybe. It'll certainly stop if you'll close VSCode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cargo build hangs with " Blocking waiting for file lock on the registry index" after building parity from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565203/cargo-build-hangs-with-blocking-waiting-for-file-lock-on-the-registry-index-a)

Comment: I closed vscode entirely and tried cargo running the project in terminal and I still get the same message

Comment: Try running `cargo clean`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244786/discussion-between-sullyh7-and-chayim-friedman).

Comment: I don't know if you have considered this, but maybe it's not an error? Sometimes I get these kind of messages too and, as the message says, it just waits until someone else frees the lock, which usually happens in under a few minutes. Have you tried waiting a little bit?

Comment: Do you have some another cargo perocess running in the background?

Comment: @BlackBeans I waited around 15 minutes and still nothing, my solution was to reinstall cargo.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I got the same problem. I am using Linux and this is how to solve it:

1. Close VS Code so that the the `rust-analyzer` extension will not be able restart `cargo`, `rust-analyzer` or `rustc`.
2. Use a resource monitoring tool (i use [btop](https://github.com/aristocratos/btop)) and search for `rust`. Kill `cargo`, `rust-analyzer` and `rustc`. Click on the process and then press `k` then `enter` to kill them on by one.
3. Try using `cargo r` again and it should work fine without displaying `"Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache"`.

I still do not know how to prevent VS Code from automatically starting the download of the packages. If you can block VS Code from auto download and instead download the packages manually when invoking `cargo r`, you can stop the process by pressing `ctrl+c` and thus stop the download if you have slow internet connection at that time for example.

Comment: Maybe setting `"rust-analyzer.cargo.autoreload":` to `false` can change the default VSCode behavior to stop auto-downloading the packages when u are on a slow internet connection.

Comment: I tried it and it works, however , there is a yellow warning on the `rust-analyzer` button at the left bottom of vscode. The analyzer seems to be working fine despite that visual warning. The packages are not downloaded automatically upon save, i don't know if that may disable other important features ...

Comment: For me it time to place vscode to trash basket.

Comment: VScode is pretty good, the only problem is that it's written in Javascript. Rust or at least C++ should have been used.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the error:

```
cd ~/.cargo
rm .package-cache
```

After these **cargo run** is working fine