# GTK: the method append exists for struct gtk::Box, but its trait bounds were not satisfied

Tags: rust, gtk

I am brand new to GTK with Rust as well as being new to the Rust language itself and I am putting together a small demo app as practice and at one point I created a `content` widget which is a `Box` class I believe.

```
let content = Box::new(Orientation: Vertical, 0);
content.append(&label);
content.append(&button);
```

I appended the widgets into my box and then on the child property of the builder I passed in the box widget, in other words `content` like so:

```
let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
     .title("UI Demo")
     .application(_app)
     .child(&content)
     .build();
```

But with the above code, I am getting an error on `append()` saying:

> GTK: the method append exists for struct gtk::Box, but its trait
> bounds were not satisfied. The following trait bounds were not
> satisfied: gtk::Box: IsA which is required by gtk::Box:
> gtk::prelude::UnixFDListExtManual gtk::Box IsA which is
> required by gtk::Box...

And it just goes on like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to you using the `gtk4` method [`append`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk4/prelude/trait.BoxExt.html#tymethod.append) on `Box` while having `gtk` (the gtk3 bindings) in your dependencies.
If you have gtk4 available on your system you can drop in replace your `gtk` dependency to:

```ini
gtk = { version = "0.5.5", package = "gtk4" }
```

in your `Cargo.toml`

If you're limited to gtk3 you have to use [the gtk3 api of `Box`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk/prelude/trait.BoxExt.html).

Comment: that seemed to work except that when I run `cargo run` in terminal it will not compile and instead just hangs on the message: ` Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache`.

Comment: Then either you have a `cargo` updating the package cache somewhere else (maybe by `rust-analyzer` in your IDE) or it crashed and left the lock file behind. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264451/blocking-waiting-for-file-lock-on-package-cache-when-i-added-dependency-to-cargo

Comment: can this be fixed by deleting the lock file and running `cargo run` again?

Comment: thanks, but I think in order for me to use the above solution, I need to have `gtk4` and I just remembered, I am on Ubuntu desktop and there is not a stable version of `gtk4` for it right now.

Comment: Maybe [`pack_end`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk/prelude/trait.BoxExt.html#tymethod.pack_end) [gtk docs](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Box.pack_end.html) is what you're looking for then, but I don't know.